# Undefined array key in wp-includes/class-wp-list-util.php

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm getting an error when I click on the abandoned cart email link.

> **Warning:** Undefined array key "line_total" in wp-includes/class-wp-list-util.php on line 169

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is 4 method to fix this error:

1: Go To Dashboard -> Update -> On You have the latest version of WordPress, click Re-Install Now.

2: try to use the default WordPress theme to see if your current theme causes this error.

3: Sounds like you are using an incompatible plugin, try disabling plugins one by one to find which plugin causes this error.

4: Finally you may disable `wp_debug` to ignore this error, go to `wp-config.php`
and find and set it to disable like the example below:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);
```

Comment: Hi Sallar define( 'WP_DEBUG', false); this is not available on my wp config file

Comment: @ThusanSelvaratnam if it is not existing, Just add it to the last line of wp-config.php

Comment: Hi done that and the error code still appears.

Comment: You may see `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true);` in your `wp-config.php` (by default: line 82) and replace it with `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);` if it is not exist, which I am sure it exist, just add to the last line: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);`

Comment: Hi do you know how to make the company field not required in woocommerce register form?

Comment: Yes I know, please mark my replay as an answer by clicking on the check mark and arrow up. And ask your question in a separate topic, I will reply on the related topic.

Comment: Hi Sallar I posted a new topic. Can you help me. Thanks